# Htaccess URL rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a challenge using Apache.

In my .htaccess file I'd like to convert requests like this:

url/portfolio/filename.htm

to:

url?filename

Any takers? Thanks for your time

Comment: Please be a little more specific. What does “url” mean in your example? And is the “portfolio” fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices, depending on how you want the URL to appear to visitors (and search engines).

If you want the externally visible URL to remain `url/portfolio/filename.htm`, Alec's solution worked after I removed the two `RewriteCond` lines.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/portfolio/(.*)\.htm$ $1?$2 [PT,L]
```

If other parameters could be in the query string and you want to preserve those, add `QSA` to the options in brackets at the end of the rule.

If you want people outside to see `url?filename` instead, change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/portfolio/(.*)\.htm$ $1?$2 [L,R]
```

Same qualification about other query parameters applies.

If this still doesn't help, I suggest you turn on rewrite logging and look in that log for more clues. Post them here and someone will help. You might have to put this part in `httpd.conf`. My Apache didn't like it in `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteLog ...path...
RewriteLogLevel 3  # you'll regret anything higher
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, although I have not tested it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)/portfolio/(.*)\.htm$ $1?$2 [PT,L]


</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Alec, thanks very much for the quick response.  I tried it and it doesn't seem to work, so I used a regex tester to see what might be up...is there chance of a 'delimiter collision' with this?  Thx D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+)\.htm$ index.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

or if you want to visibly change it:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+)\.htm$ /?$1 [R,NC,L]
```

The second one would look like *example.com/?filename* to the user, whereas the first one would look like *example.com/portfolio/filename.htm*.

Hope that helps.